# How to enable ActiveRecord Oracle OCI8 ORA-03113 AutoRecover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, ora-03113

I am using activerecord with oracle enhaced adapter and oci8. I am having some trouble with the ORA-03113 error. I believe that using OCI8 AutoRecover could solve my problem, though, I cannot find anywere how to tell activerecord to use this functionality? Is there an option in the database.yml file? Is there any piece of code that I must run in order to activate it?

Technologies:
Oracle 10g
ActiveRecord 3.2.14
ruby 1.9.3

This is a non-Rails project.

Comment: does the reconnect parameter not work? Try specifying `reconnect: true` in your configuration yaml.

Comment: are you sure that this parameter exists? I have no easy way to reproducce this situation.

Comment: ah, I missed that you were using AR 2.3 - we're using 3.2 and it is likely introduced there.

Comment: I am acctually using 3.2.14. it was a mistype. thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm unsure if it will do what you need, since we run on mysql here.  But from the parameter name I guess the intent is to reconnect when a connection dies or is closed by the server - hopefully it will sort out your oracle issue too :-)